# Firebase Realtime Database do broadcast operation even when there is no subscriber

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I have came across with problem that Firebase Realtime Database generates too much download traffic.

In my application I only write to the database using:

```
database.child("child").setValue(value)
```

While researching the problem with Firebase's [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/database-profile#listener-broadcast) I found that there is listener_broadcast operation on each write operation and that broadcast generate download traffic despite the fact that I do not subscribe to read data anywhere.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem. Namely I would like to disable this broadcast operation

Comment: I'm not aware of any broadcast operation. Can you show that?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/database-profile#listener-broadcast @AlexMamo